# ASP.NET MVC - Workaround for consecutive segments in routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a route defined as `{file}.{extension}`
with the following constraints:
`file: index|start|inicio|comienzo`
`extension: asp|aspx|htm|html`

So, the routing works fine with `index.asp` or `start.html` for example.

But this is not essentially what I want, I would also want that `index` or `start` (without an `extension` segment) be valid routes.

The problem is that the routing `{file}{extension}`
with an `extension` constraint of `(\.(asp|aspx|htm|html))?`
doesn't work because ASP.NET MVC Routing Handler does not support consecutive segments.

Do you have any ideas of how to implement this in only one route?, and not declaring another one with just the `{file}` segment.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking this is impossible to do with one route...isn't it?!